# Why I can't inherit from System.Tuple in F#

Tags: f#, sealed

using Visual Studio 2017 I'm trying to compile the following F# snippet

```
type Foo() =
inherit System.Tuple<string,string>("","")
```

which fails telling me that I cannot inherit from sealed type. I inspected FSharp.Core and it's not sealed. I'm also convinced that this compiled with VS 2010.

Any ideas? Is this caused by extra F# metadata? I know that F# treats tuples in special way

Comment: I get the same message, I suspect that it actually is sealed for F#. What you are doing here is definitely outside the norm. What are you intending to do? There likely is a good way to do what you are actually trying to do without creating a new inherited type.

Comment: The Tuple defined in FSharp.Core is only there for backwards compatibility with versions of .NET Framework that don't have a built-in System.Tuple type (prior to 4.5). In most cases you're actually using the System.Tuple defined in the runtime rather than the one in FSharp.Core. Perhaps the runtime type is sealed, or something about the type-redirects involved in using the runtime type means F# has to treat it as if it is sealed?

Comment: @MichalMa is that an actual production scenario you have there? One more reason to stay on good old VS2010 ;)

Answer (score 2):

As of F# 4.1, F# treats all `System.Tuple` instances as an F# tuple, which cannot be inherited from.